# How to delete partition Microsoft basic data on Pop!_OS

Tags: linux, partition, pop-os

After installing Pop!_OS, I expected all Windows/Microsoft data to be overritten.

Due to a `fdisk -l` scan, I still have a 4G partition of "Microsoft basic data partition" type.

How to delete, this `/dev/nvme0n1p2`, data partition and merge it with the Linux filesystem?

I don't run dual-boot; the previous OS was Windows Education.

```bash
Device             Start        End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1      4096    1023998   1019903   498M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2   1024000    9412606   8388607     4G Microsoft basic data
/dev/nvme0n1p3   9412608  991822510 982409903 468.4G Linux filesystem
/dev/nvme0n1p4 991822512 1000211118   8388607     4G Linux swap
```

Comment: why wouldn't you be able to delete any partition or format any partition that you like?

Comment: I  don't know how to delete this partition on linux `/dev/nvme0n1p2   1024000    9412606   8388607     4G Microsoft basic data` and if deleted how to merge the `partiion ` to the linux filesystem

Comment: then edit your post ... change `Could I delete this partition ...?` to `How can I delete this partition ...?`

Answer (score 1):

Your `nvme0n1p2` partition is exactly the same size as your current swap partition. You could change the type of `nvme0n1p2` to "Linux swap", then reinitialize it as a new swap partition with `sudo mkswap /dev/nvme0n1p2`, look up its new UUID with `lsblk -o +UUID`, then replace all references to `nvme0n1p4` or its UUID by the new device name/UUID.

You could use `sudo grep -r nvme0n1p4 /etc` and `sudo grep -r <old swap UUID here> /etc` to find the configuration where the swap area is mentioned. One of them is most likely `/etc/fstab`, but there may be other configuration files related to suspend/hibernate functionality. After updating the configuration files, update your initramfs with `sudo update-inintramfs -u`, then reboot. Use `sudo swapon -s` to verify that your system is now using `nvme0n1p2` rather than `nvme0n1p4` as its swap area.

After this operation, you can delete the `nvme0n1p4` partition and use its space to extend the `nvme0n1p3` partition. This is easier and safer than deleting nvme0n1p2, moving the entire contents of the (previous) `nvme0n1p3` towards the beginning of the disk, and then extending the partition, as partitions can only be extended at their "tail" end. It also avoids the extra complication of `nvme0n1p3` becoming `nvme0n1p2` at some point of the process.

If you are unfamiliar with partition manipulations, you should use a GUI tool such as `gparted` for this.